# Error with angular & angular/cli versions

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I have this error on angular docker project:

```
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0-next || >=13.0.0 <14.0.0,
industrialareas_angular_ctnr | but Angular version 12.2.16 was found instead.
```

My Dockerfile-angular file is:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
RUN npm uninstall @angular/cli
RUN npm i @angular/cli@12.2.8
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY ./project/package*.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm link @angular/cli
COPY ./project .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD npm start
```

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  angular:
    container_name: industrialareas_angular_ctnr
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-angular
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./project/src:/usr/src/app/src
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
```

And the package.json file is:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "@angular/cli": "~12.2.8",
  ...
```

I have checked compatibility versions on this [link](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3)

Anybody could help me please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide here the result of `ng --version` command? Maybe `@angular/cli` is installed globally and its version is higher than `12.2.8`.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a more complete [mcve]?  You mention a Docker project and the error message looks like Docker Compose output; what's in your Dockerfile, and are you doing something like using a anonymous volume for your `node_modules` tree in the `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular CLI version that u declared in JSON isn't compatible with Angular core version u used: would be more clear if u post whole package.json file content.

To solve issue, you can either upgrade angular core version to 13.0.0 and next, or you can downgrade angular cli version: the link doesn't come from official documentation, so it's not viable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that node brings the latest predefined version of angular cli, specifically @angular/cli@13.2.3 and the docker command took that by default.

Replace this line on Dockerfile:

```
RUN npm link @angular/cli
```

to this:

```
RUN npm link @angular/cli@12.2.8
```

and all works ok !